# How to pass inherited attribute to custom validator

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, customvalidator

I am trying to pass an inherited attribute into the `IsValid()` error message in a custom attribute validator. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do so after searching online for this.

I have a class named `MarketConfiguration`

```
public class MarketConfiguration : BaseConfiguration
{
    [Required]
    [AcceptedStores(0,2,11)]
    public int Store {get; set;}
}
```

where `BaseConfiguration`

```
public class BaseConfiguration
{
    
    private string _manufactureId;
    
    [Required]
    public string ManufactureId
    {
        get { return _manufactureId; }
        set
        {
            _manufactureId = value.Trim();
        }
    }

}
```

where my custom validator contains

```
public class AcceptedStores : ValidationAttribute
{

    private readonly int[] _store;
    private readonly int _manufacturerId;

    public AllowedIntegers(int[] store)
    {
        _store = store;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        int storesToValidate = (int)value;
        
        if(!_store.Contains(storesToValidate))
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"For manufacturerID {_manufacturerId}, the store {_store} does not match. Please enter correct values.");
        }
        
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

but the error message does not return the manufacturerId.. only the store value.

I pass this in json body in postman

```
[
  { 
   "manufacturerId": "7893",
   "store": 93
   }
]
```

Is there a way to pass manufacturerId into the error message that is in the custom validator for Store?

Comment: who is setting _manufacturerId? why is it marked readonly?

Comment: why not use ValidationContext‘s ObjectInstance? cast it to  BaseConfiguration  to get ManufactureId https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.objectinstance?view=net-8.0

Comment: @RandRandom I made readonly only to say it doesn't get changed.... but essentially I am passing the value for manufactuerId in postman so perhaps I can remove `readonly`.

Comment: @RandRandom I am sorry, what do you mean by this? Not following what you said "why not use ValidationContext‘s ObjectInstance? cast it to BaseConfiguration to get ManufactureId"

Comment: `var mId = ((BaseConfiguration)validationContext.ObjectInstance).ManufactureId;`

Comment: Ah I see, was not aware that this can be done with ObjectInstance, thanks for this solution!